# Dropdown menu cutting off

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I click on the menu to expand it, Page also gets expanded and a scroll bar comes for the page. or it gets cut off. How can I solve this using bootstrap?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light bg-light">

  <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-start">
    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <div class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle user-action"> P<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Profile creation</a></a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> Calendar</a></a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i> Settings</a></a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8AC;</i> Logout</a></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/thisisnone/pen/ZEeXKaV)

Comment: Please fix the snippet so it shows your problem. No need to link us elsewhere or show images.

Comment: the code pen doesn't work either

Comment: @Ruben link corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add  `dropdown dropdown-menu-right` to your dropdown.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

[Menu only shows in full page demo mode.]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light bg-light">

  <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-start">
    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <div class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle user-action">Menu<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Profile creation</a></a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> Calendar</a></a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i> Settings</a></a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8AC;</i> Logout</a></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```